# Making a counter for #StopTheFire

Tags: javascript, counter

So,  I just wanted to make a counter for #StopTheFire Which how can I extract the number from `<span>`? I also saw some post on twitter asking about this.  With JavaScript. Can I use WrapAPI for this?  Thanks.

Part of the code from StopTheFire.gg:

```
<span>$25,692</span>
```

[image: Photo]

Comment: Sorry for wrong numbers.

Comment: Well, if you have access to the document you can do `document.querySelector("#total-donation-amount-cents > span").innerText;`

Comment: I don't have the access to the document.

Comment: if you search up "web scraping in JS" you'll find tutorials about how to scrape data from a webpage (which is what you're after)

Answer (score 0):

Get the html of the site

Use jQuery:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'your-url', success: function(data) { alert(data); } });
```

This data is your HTML.

.getElementsByTagName("span") will return you a collection of elements. Here you might have to parse first and select by id or class because there will be wrong spans...

Then, you might want to use .innerHTML:

For your case you would just loop through

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
```

and for each of those

```
var array_values = []
var value;
for(key in spans) {
 value = spans[key].innerHTML;
 array_values.push(value)
}
```